# multiple claim with same amount

Tags: erc-20

my smart contract is deployed to mainnet and my claim function has deadline of 2 min but in between user can go to explorer and claim the amount twice and I cant chnage contract code because there are customer data which moving is very risky. any other solution so user can claim only one time from one amount

Comment: Share the contract code and then ask the questions bro, it's hard for the community to answer something without knowing the details.

Comment: Please share the deployed contract address, and the minimal reproducible code for the contract.